# How to wait for a Function to return values and finish to run another Function with Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, jquery, multithreading

As the thread's title with SharePoint 2010, this worked well with all browsers as the demo below. However, when I'd tried to get the information from another link (it must be another thread of SharePoint). Thus, that code didn't work anymore.

---

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/yh755/)**</kbd>

Result:

- a done
- b done
- FunctionTwo

---

**My Javascript as my current problem:**

```
var FunctionOne = function () {
  var
a = $.Deferred(),
b = $.Deferred();

  // some fake asyc task
  // Get information from another site
   var set_current_login_name = currentUser.get_title(); //The code to get information goes here
   alert(set_current_login_name); // Result: "Transportation"
   a.resolve();

  // some other fake asyc task
  alert('b done');
  b.resolve();

  return $.Deferred(function (def) {
  $.when(a, b).done(function () {
  def.resolve();
      });
  });
};

var FunctionTwo = function () {
    alert('FunctionTwo');
};

FunctionOne().done(FunctionTwo);
```

Result:

- b done
- FunctionTwo
- Transportation

**The Result must be like this:**

- Transportation
- b done
- FunctionTwo

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Also, what do you mean by "information from another link"? Are going cross domain?

Comment: **@PaulT.**: That's it with the jQuery 1.11.0

Comment: Ok. Older versions of jQuery had some issue with the pipe'ing of Deferreds.  One other question: if you want squential code execution, why are you using Deferreds?